# Free Virtual Machine Recommendations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

Is there any permanent free compute engine like GCP offered (VM) to host my simple python script to send out daily message ?

Comment: Your question will get closed because you have not clearly defined a problem that you are trying to solve and you are asking for recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Without your script it's a bit hard to tell but I think a whole instance to run a script daily might be too much. Most of the cloud providers have a free tier that you could probably sit comfortably in if you reduce the compute to only when the script actually needs to run.

My recommendation for this use case is to use the [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) trigger service to schedule how often you'd like to run your script and have it call a cloud function that runs only when needed (i.e. once a day).

All the major clouds will have their own equivalent approaches for this same solution.

### Google

[Cron Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler)

[Python Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python).

### Azure

[Azure Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp)

[Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/)

Answer (score 0):

Google offers more than just a free VM in their [Always Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free) and based on your requirement of running a Python script on schedule, I would recommend Cloud Functions and then use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/pricing) (you can have up to 3 jobs free per month) with Pub/Sub to trigger your function.

Here's a [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub)